html to vs code
I know this seems like it should be a simple task, but I'm new and learning so here we go. How do I take my existing HTML code created in notepad and bring it over to VS Code without just copy and pasting the code? Thanks
I haven't tried much as I'm trying to figure out the best practices.

Are you asking how to open an existing file in VS Code?

I believe so? I want to add JavaScript and CSS to the code through vs.

I think your reworking of the question helped me figure it out. Thank you @Ry

VSC is just like Notepad, an editor, you don't bring files to Notepad and also not to VSC

I think you can read throught this link.
Which you can do to open html file via vscode is
Create a New File :
Go to the "File" menu in the top bar and select "New File" (or press Cmd + N on macOS or Ctrl + N on Windows/Linux).
This creates a new file specifically for your HTML code, keeping your project organized.
Alternatively, Open an Existing File:
If you already have your HTML code saved in a file, go to the "File" menu and select "Open File" (or press Cmd + O on macOS or Ctrl + O on Windows/Linux).
Navigate to the location where your HTML file is saved and select it.

So I tried opening the files with Vs code and it imported everything but when editing the code its giving me a few errors. (Example) When linking a newley created html file page to my pre made html file using  Link Name  it adds the link onto the website but when clicked says the file isn't avalible

I dont think this is relate to your head question. But I think you need to learn about how to use  in html from this resource. [Hint] this error mean you dont have this filename.html in the directory
